# facebook iOS - share- not showing app icon when posting on wall

Tags: xcode, facebook, icons, share, photo

I followed the login and share tutorial on developers.facebook.com and when posting on wall the app icon does not appear on post. it only shows labels and user input text. how do I make that app icon to show? does it have to be uploaded or is it something that I configure? before posting any answers or recomendations I already uploaded a photo to the developers.facebook dashboard. thank you in advance.. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/ :

```
self.postParams =
    [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
     @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
     @"https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/iossdk_logo.png", @"picture",
     @"Facebook SDK for iOS", @"name",
     @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
     @"The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps.", @"description",
     nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone who had the same problem.. just upload the icon into a photo sharing site like photo bucket and assign that link to the code..